# How do you develop for facebook? (multiple developers)

Tags: facebook

I'm currently developing a Facebook App for an Application Tab with another developer (CodeIgniter Framework).

It's not possible to use localhost for Application Tabs. So we're using subversion for updating our stuff on our server to test the app in facebook. Quite often we have conflicts in our files, because we're editing the same parts of it.

Is there any better solution to develop a Facebook App with multiple developers?

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your "hosts" file in C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc

`//Under...`

127.0.0.1       localhost

`//Add...`

127.0.0.1       yourappname.com

This will allow you to run the application locally...

Comment: It tried this one. When I now visit the URL in my browser it shows the stuff that's running locally.

Looking at the Application Tab in Facebook it shows the stuff that's on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Xander is right and here's what we are doing in our dev team :

1. setup facebook app
2. setup on our localhost
3. create a virtual host like dev.facebookapp.com via apache
4. make sure you have svn or git to lessen conflicts with other dev